# Exchange 2010 Export to PST using just Keywords

Tags: exchange, export, mailbox

I'm trying to Export one of our Mailboxes into a .PST file and having problems finding the right cmdlets. We are trying to export certain keywords of a users mailbox. I've tried using the cmdlet of `-ContentFilter {All -like "*Keyword Test*"}` without any luck.

This is what I've tried so far, but without any luck.

```
New-MailboxExportRequest -ContentFilter {All -like "*Keyword Test*"} -Mailbox “Pelton” -Name DPeltonExp -FilePath \ExServer1\Imports\DPelton.pst
```

I've also tried the other following, but all .PST are empty of any emails.

```
New-MailboxExportRequest -ContentFilter {All -like "Firstword Secondword"} -Mailbox “Pelton” -Name DPeltonExp -FilePath \ExServer1\Imports\DPelton.pst

New-MailboxExportRequest -ContentFilter {All -eq "Firstword Secondword"} -Mailbox “Pelton” -Name DPeltonExp -FilePath \ExServer1\Imports\DPelton.pst

New-MailboxExportRequest -ContentFilter {All -eq "*Firstword Secondword*"} -Mailbox “Pelton” -Name DPeltonExp -FilePath \ExServer1\Imports\DPelton.pst
```

Any and all help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Please try using the **Export-Mailbox** command rather than New-MailboxExportRequest

```
Export-Mailbox -Identity <MailboxIdParameter> -TargetMailbox <MailboxIdParameter> -TargetFolder <Target_Folder_Name> -ContentKeywords "<String[]>" -AttachmentFilenames "<String[]>" -StartDate "<Month/Day/Year> <Time>" -RecipientKeywords <String[]>
```